# Create a user and auto login

Tags: users

I use `user_save()` to create a new user in a custom module. If the function returns `TRUE`, is it possible to auto login the user?

**EDIT**

I've done some more searching and found the `user_authenticate()`

This is the code I have so far:

```
$user_info = array(
  'name' => $sessdata['username'],
  'pass' => user_password(),
  'mail' => $sessdata['username'],
  'init' => $sessdata['username'],
  'status' => 1,
  'roles' => array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => TRUE),
                    'access' => time(),
                    );
  $save = user_save($account,$user_info);



  if($save) {
    $loggedin = user_authenticate($save->name, $save->pass);

    if($loggedin) {
      echo "logged in";
    } else {
      echo "damn";
    }
  }
```

Well it saves the user but it doesn't logins him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `user_save()` returns a user object, not `TRUE`. If it doesn't return `FALSE`, then the function was successful and you can use the returned object to log in that user.

For example, supposing that `$user` is the user object returned from `user_save()`, you can use the following code to replace the currently logged in user with that user (the code is for Drupal 7).

```
drupal_save_session(FALSE);
$original_user = $GLOBALS['user'];
$GLOBALS['user'] = $user;

// Do what you need.

$GLOBALS['user'] = $original_user;
drupal_save_session(TRUE);
```

The code can be used to do some actions impersonating another user, or when a user follows a link reported him in an email, which allows the user to log in. In the latter case, the last two lines should be removed from the code executed.

Without setting the value of `$GLOBAL['user']`, there isn't any way to let Drupal think a user is logged in.

`user_authenticate()` is not working because you are not passing the password for that account. In fact, Drupal doesn't save the password in any places; it saves the hash of the password, but that is not what [user_authenticate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_authenticate/7) needs, as reported from its documentation page:

> #### Parameters
>
> $name User name to authenticate.
>
> $password A plain-text password, such as trimmed text from form values.
>
> #### Return value
>
> The user's uid on success, or FALSE on failure to authenticate.

The function passed its `$password` parameter to [user_check_password()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--password.inc/function/user_check_password/7), which execute the following code:

```
  if (substr($account->pass, 0, 2) == 'U$') {
    // This may be an updated password from user_update_7000(). Such hashes
    // have 'U' added as the first character and need an extra md5().
    $stored_hash = substr($account->pass, 1);
    $password = md5($password);
  }
  else {
    $stored_hash = $account->pass;
  }

  $type = substr($stored_hash, 0, 3);
  switch ($type) {
    case '$S$':
      // A normal Drupal 7 password using sha512.
      $hash = _password_crypt('sha512', $password, $stored_hash);
      break;
    case '$H$':
      // phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing as "$P$".
    case '$P$':
      // A phpass password generated using md5.  This is an
      // imported password or from an earlier Drupal version.
      $hash = _password_crypt('md5', $password, $stored_hash);
      break;
    default:
      return FALSE;
  }
  return ($hash && $stored_hash == $hash);
```

As you see, `$account->pass` is used as stored hash of the password, while you are passing that value as password.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer clears a lot! This code works if I am already logged in and then indeed it changes the logged in user, but not when no one is logged in. I need to be able to log in to a drupal site, by visiting a link from a different site to a custom module I am building.

Comment: I've added to your code this: $form_state = array();
      $form_state['uid'] = $user->uid;      
      user_login_submit(array(), $form_state); and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

To login a user do

```
global $user;
$user = $save;
```

Comment: Will that work with register_globals_off ?

Comment: It works, but after I set the $user = $save , I use drupal_goto() and the access is denied..

Comment: DO I need to enter an entry to the sessions table, somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is [`user_login_finalize`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_finalize/7). This takes the current value of `$GLOBALS['user']` and sets that user as the logged in user.

To create and log in a user, try the following:

```php
// Operate on the global $user variable so it is available to
// user_login_finalize() when called.
global $user;

// Create a user. The password is set to a random 10-digit
// as generated by user_password().
$user_info = array(
  'name' => 'USERNAME',
  'pass' => user_password(),
  'roles' => array(
    DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => TRUE,
  ),
  'mail' => 'E-MAIL ADDRESS',
  'init' => 'E-MAIL ADDRESS',
  'status' => 1,
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'timezone' => NULL,
);

// Add the 'ROLE_NAME' role
$rid = array_search('ROLE_NAME', user_roles());
$user_info['roles'][$rid] = TRUE;

// Set a value for FIELD_NAME
$user_info['FIELD_NAME'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array('value' => '…');

// Set the $GLOBALS['user'] to the newly created user account
$user = user_save(NULL, $user_info);

// Finalize user login (modify $_SESSION, set login time in db)
user_login_finalize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code in validation function:

```
$form_state['uid'] = user_authenticate($form_state['values']['name'], $form_state['values']['pass']);
```

Submit function (user_login_submit) will automatically log in user.

Answer (score 0):

none of the above worked for me

instead i did the following:

```
if($save){
  $uid = user_authenticate($username , $password); 
  // do not need to hash the password
  $user = user_load($uid);
  $form_state = array();
  $form_state['uid'] = $uid;
  user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);
}
```