# login programmatically not work

Tags: users

according to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19436/create-a-user-and-auto-login)  I wrote below code to create temp user and login ,
, user create but it not logged in.
where is problem?

```
   $user_info = array(
  'name' => 'temp-payment-'.rand(1,999),
  'pass' => user_password(),
  'mail' => 'no@no.com',
  'init' => 'temp-user-'.rand(1,999),
  'status' => 1,
  'roles' => array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => TRUE),
                    'access' => time(),
                    );
  $user = user_save('',$user_info);



  if($user) {
   $GLOBALS['user'] = $user;
    drupal_save_session(TRUE);
    ym($user);
  }
  drupal_goto('/user');
```

Comment: Also relevant: [How do I programmatically log in a user?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/how-do-i-programmatically-log-in-a-user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is

```
 $form_state['uid'] = $user->uid;
 user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);
```

and final code :

```
$user_info = array(
  'name' => 'temp-payment-'.rand(1,999),
  'pass' => user_password(),
  'mail' => 'no@no.com',
  'init' => 'temp-user-'.rand(1,999),
  'status' => 1,
  'roles' => array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => TRUE),
                    'access' => time(),
                    );
  $user = user_save('',$user_info);
//drupal_save_session(FALSE);
//$loggedin = user_authenticate($user->name, $user->pass);
//ym($loggedin);
$form_state['uid'] = $user->uid;
 user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);
//drupal_save_session(FALSE);
$GLOBALS['user'] = $user;
drupal_save_session(TRUE);
//drupal_goto('/user');
```

**hope be useful for another users,**.

**This code generate and login to it programmatically**